# How to play with the CloudApp API in CURL?

Tags: api, curl

I am trying to play with the CloudApp API with CURL and it keeps giving me the redirect message, and I don't think I'm initializing it right. The docs are at http://support.getcloudapp.com/faqs/developers/api and my request currently looks like:

```
curl -G --digest -u user@domain.com:[censored] -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://my.cl.ly/items/new
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also need to include -H "Accept: application/json"